# Postgresql copy from CSV with dynamic date

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-9.3

I have the following `Command` table in a `postgresql 9.3` database:

```
Command
-------------------------------------------------------------
id               | purchased_date                       | ...
integer NOT NULL | timestamp without time zone NOT NULL | ...
```

Now I want to fill my table with data from a CSV file. My CSV file contains for example the following values:

```
1,"2016-04-18 09:37:30"
2,"2016-04-17 09:37:30" 
...
```

When I do `\i 'my_csv_file.csv'` it works great. What I want to do now is to have the CSV file with dynamic dates in order to not regenerate the CSV file when I want to reload my database (this is for test purposes). I would like to have something like:

```
1,"CURRENT_DATETIME - INTERVAL '1 DAY'"
2,"CURRENT_DATETIME - INTERVAL '2 DAY'"
```

But when I execute the same command `\i 'my_csv_file.csv'` I have the error `ERROR:  date/time value "current" is no longer supported`. Is that possible to do what I want ?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary table with offsets, then insert from it.

CSV:

```
1,"INTERVAL '1 DAY'"
2,"INTERVAL '2 DAY'"
```

Queries:

```
create temporary table tmp_table (
  id int,
  offset_ interval
);
```

Import csv into this table, then

```
insert into main_table (id, purchased_date ) 
   (select id, now()-offset_ from tmp_table);
```